# Loading model in tensorflowjs from string

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I have a json string representing a model stored in a js variable. I created it using a gui that generates this json. I would like to load it to tensorflow using `tf.loadModel`, but the API only accepts url or localstorage. Is there any way to do it directly from string?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Tensorflow.js doesn't provide any way to do this currently.

However, if you need to do it with a string, a possible workaround is to save the string directly to localStorage and retrieve it from there with the URI.

Something like this (untested):

```
var modelJson = { ... }
localStorage.setItem('model', JSON.stringify(modelJson))
const model = await tf.loadModel('localstorage://model');
```